# Why are operations on primitive types unsequenced instead of indeterminitely sequenced?

Tags: c++, c++11, undefined-behavior, sequence-points

If `i` is an `int`, expressions like `++i + ++i` are undefined behavior since there are 2 unsequenced modifications of `i`.  However, if `i` is some `int`-like class, `++i + ++i` instead has indeterminately sequenced modifications, and is therefore defined behavior (with a deterministic result in this case).  Is there a case where it would be better to have operations on primitives be unsequenced instead of indeterminately sequenced?  If so, why doesn't this case apply to user-created types?  If not, why are primitive operations unsequenced at all?

Comment: Being undefined behaviour presumably allows the compiler to apply certain classes of optimisations. It's unlikely that these optimisations apply to UDTs, in general, as ++i is then just syntax sugar for a function call.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, there is as much "unsequenced" as possible.

It is not possible to make two functions run interleaving in C++. Therefor, it is not possible to run two `operator++` implementations interleaving.

Therefor, for class types implementing `operator++`, this is indeterminately sequenced.